# how to change mac app store info.plist?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, code-signing, mac-app-store

I want to tweak some apps appearance through their info.plist.

But apps installer via Mac App Store don't open after that, because their signing validations (I'm running Yosemite).

Is there a way I can tweak them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, turns out it's very easy.

I just had to run the code signing tool:

`sudo codesign -f -s - /path_to_app.app`

But I will have to change the info.plist and run this every time the app is updated.